# Сделать загрузку из двух форм в базу данных

Tags: php, form, mysql

Подскажите как код реализовать + доработать занос в базу данных
В чём суть вопроса:
Есть у меня 3 файла

1. index.php
2. confirmation.php
3. save.php

В чем проблема, мне нужно сделать загрузку из формы в базу данных но у меня 2 формы и должны заносится в базу как 1 форма,

Содержимое index.php

```
<form method="post" action="confirmation.php">
Имя: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>
Фамилия: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
</form>
```

Содержимое confirmation.php

```
<form method="post" action="save.php">
Город: <input type="text" name="gorod" id="gorod" /><br>
Телефон: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
</form>
```

Содержимое save.php

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
if (isset($_POST['lname'])) {$lname = $_POST['lname'];}
if (isset($_POST['gorod'])) {$gorod = $_POST['gorod'];}
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}
?>
<?php

$db = mysql_connect("Хост","Пользователь","пароль");
if(!$db) {echo "База не подключена";}
mysql_select_db("база");

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `userinfo` (`name`, `lname`, `gorod`, `phone`) VALUES ('$name','$lname','$gorod','$phone')");

if($result == 'true')
{
echo "<h1>Категория добавлена успешно!</h1>";
}
else
{
echo "<h1>Категория не добавлена!</h1>";
}
?>
```

Как у меня это работает, в index.php есть маленькая форма где надо ввести Имя и Фамилию, когда он вводит жмёт продолжит вылетает окно и там уже введите Город и телефон, вот не знаю как сделать что бы эти данные заносились в базу данных

Answer (score 2):

в Вашем случае измените confirmation.php

```
<form method="post" action="save.php">
<?php
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="'.$_POST['name'].'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lname" id="lname" value="'.$_POST['lname'].'" />';
?>

Город: <input type="text" name="gorod" id="gorod" /><br>
Телефон: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
</form>
```

Получается на втором шаге вы принимаете данные из первой формы и передаёте их дальше.
Но такие пошаговые вещи лучше проверять на каждом шагу.

Answer (score 0):

Между страницами данные можно передавать внутри сессий.
Подробнее: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

Или печеньками воспользоваться. Как вариант, конечно. Хотя решение с сессией по моему - проще и надежней.

И все-же, если интересно:
[Руководство по PHP - Cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php)